# Reliable way to know user's last connected DateTime?

Tags: c#, cookies, membership

I'd like to add a bit of functionality to my site, which shows "new stuff" since the last time the user was on the site. My site is ASP.NET MVC/C#/Razor based.

What's a reliable way to get/set that DateTime?

**Update**: sorry I didn't include this originally... I'm not using the built-in membership code. My site uses the Facebook C# SDK, log in is through Fb, I store to a standard Members table.

Comment: @GertArnold - no, I'm not trying to use any of the Fb mechanisms (there aren't any) to know when a user last logged in.

Perhaps some sort of cookie/DB entry combination? Since I've never done it before, not sure if it's reliable.

Comment: Ok. So this Members table is in a database of you own? Can you use the time of the database server?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am using asp.net membership provider which allows me to store the last time (DateTime) the users logged in. This could be a solution to set that DateTime. Then, you can always get that value just before performing the login function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that I wasn't using the standard ASP.NET membership. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net Member ship then you can get last login date by

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(login.UserName);
DateTime dtLastLogin = user.LastLoginDate;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that I wasn't using the standard ASP.NET membership. I updated my question.